# Web3 - Access return value of events

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging

I want to get the value that my smart contract returns in javascript.

Here is the contract. (version 0.4.25 - web3 version 1.2)

```js
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
contract SimpleStorage {

    uint public storedData;
    event numberSaved(uint number);

    constructor(uint initVal) public {
        storedData = initVal;
    }

    function set(uint x) public{
        storedData = x;
        emit numberSaved(storedData);
    }

    function get() view public returns (uint retVal) {
        return storedData;
    }

}
```

Now how do I get the value the event returned?

I tried with:

```
mySmartContract.events.numberSaved();
```

[image: Returns object]

```
mysmartContract.once('numberSaved', function(error, event){ console.log(event); });
```

This one returns null

What am I doing wrong?

It works in Remix.
[image: Remix returns the value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
result.events.numberSaved.returnValues['number']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysmartContract.getPastEvents('numberSaved', {
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}, function(error, events){ console.log(events); })
.then(function(events){
    console.log(events) // same results as the optional callback above
});
```

Actually, I took the example from [Web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents).